# App Engine Java Flex Environment and MySQL Second Generation are compatibles?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, google-app-engine

Anybody knows if the App Engine Java Flex Environment and MySQL Second Generation are compatibles?

Already followed all the instructions to setup a project using the Java Flex Environment, until that point everything is on rails, but, when I try to connect my project with a second generation MySQL instance, I received the next error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

My URL for connecting to the server is:

jdbc:mysql://google/database1?cloudSqlInstance=project:us-central1:instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=root

I'm using Maven to create the dependencies, this is the XML:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems to be everything ok.

Any Suggestions?